# How can I use localStorageService in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

LocalStorageService(https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) provides service that help me to save data with localstorage.
For example,

```
angular.module(app)
.controller("mainController",function(localStorageService){
    localStorageService.set("now",new Date());
});
```

A service I made needs some local data and I inject LocalStorageService into it. However, I feel this bad way to use LocalStorageService. I think each service should be independence, or alone. So, to use LocalStorageService, I think I should use config to load data at first and save data in controller. Is this right? How can I use localStorageService in angular? Please teach me!

I made Calendar Service. If this depends on localStorageService, I cannot use this service in another situation without localStorageService. Its dependency makes me feel it bad way. I have heard that modules should be independent as possible some times.

(Calendar Service has three properties. Two properties are number, one shows Calendar's month and other shows Calendar's year. Rest property is an array which contains dates.)

Comment: it's not really clear what you are trying to ask here.  Are you asking for explanation of the documentation, or for examples of use? Or are you just ranting about how you don't like the design patterns the module uses?

Comment: I want to know where to use localStorageService. Now, I use this in service, but I think I should use this in controller. Which is true to use localStorageService, service or controller? It depends on circumstance and I should change how to use?

Comment: use it in a service if your service needs it?  You still aren't clarifying the question, other than to make it more obvious that you aren't concerned with the module at all, rather the architecture of your application, which you haven't described at all.

Comment: if your question is "should I be using this module in a service or a controller?", it's not answerable unless we know what the service and controller are doing, and why you think using this module in a service is a "bad way" isn't really clear.

Comment: It's perfectly ok for a service to use another service.

Comment: (I'm learning English, so I couldn't understand what you said conpletely.) I want to know which is true to use. angular.module(app).service("ServiceA",["localStorageService",function(LSS){...}]) or angular.module.controller("mainController",["ServiceA","localStorageService",function(serviceA,LSS){...}]);

Comment: Both of those methods are acceptable ways to use a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
.factory('LocalStorageService', function(){

  return {
    setItem: function(key, obj) {
      var objToString = JSON.stringify(obj);
      window.localStorage.setItem(key, objToString);
    },
    getItem: function(key) {
      var str = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
      var stringToJSON = JSON.parse(str);
      return stringToJSON;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry to add examples of use localStorageService. This factory is same to localStorageService... I want to know how to use this service in another service. Using this service in another service makes the service dependent on localStorageService.  When I use the service dependent on localStorageService, I couldn't use the service without localStorageService.

Comment: with DI...

`.factory('AnotherService', function(LocalStorageService){})`